# Screen Orientation in Expo Managed App React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, screen-orientation

I'm relatively new to React Native and am building an app using an Expo managed workflow. I have my application's orientation set to "portrait" in my app.json. While this keeps the orientation of my application in portrait, I have noticed that when I rotate my device, the underlying device switches orientations. I can see this because the status bar shifts.

Does anyone know how to lock the device's orientation and not just the application's? Everything I have found directs me to Expo's ScreenOrientation API, but that appears to have the same problem as well, it doesn't seem to lock the device's screen orientation.

Comment: Hey Evan, did you manage to find a fix for this?

Comment: Once I launched in TestFlight, this was resolved. This appears to be an issue only while working in the Expo app. For testing, you can just lock your screen orientation through your device's settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I launched in TestFlight, this was resolved. This appears to be an issue only while working in the Expo app. For testing, you can just lock your screen orientation through your device's settings.